# Use pre upgrade .Values in if conditions in pre-upgrade hook - Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to know if it is possible to evaluate {{- If .Values.config }} and fail in a pre-upgrade hook if config is not set, which it shouldn't exist in the chart previous to the upgrade, but is part of the new chart version values.yaml.

This is because the upgrade hooks should only run if that value didn't exist, otherwise it means is already upgraded. Currently when evaluating .Values.config in the pre-upgrade hook it returns the new .Values even though the chart is in the process of being upgraded.

This I would think it should fail but it doesn't

```
{{- if .Values.config }}
{{ fail "Already upgraded" }}
{{- else }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: "dbdump"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-1"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": keep
    "helm.sh/resource-policy": keep
```

thanks for your help

Comment: From looking at the Helm docs on [hooks](https://helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/#hooks) and the [built-in objects available in templates](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#built-in-objects), it's not clear to me that there's any way to get the previous values or any metadata about the previous version on an upgrade.

Comment: A bit hacky way would be to run a test before upgrading with a container running helm. You could do a `helm get values XXX`, evaluate the result and fail the test/hook based on that command.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Not sure if I understood correctly @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst but I wouldn't know how to trigger that container running helm without a hook that already gets running time .Values

Comment: 1. You build your own container which includes the helm binary.
2. In your chart, you create a job resource on the `pre-install` helm hook and mount `{{ .Values.config }}` somewhere into the container from step 1.
3. The container should run a `helm get values` on your chart which you can then compare to the `{{ .Values.config }}` mounted in the container.
4. Depending on the outcome you fail the helm installation or not.